# MSGraph login with Laravel. Delegated login flow

Tags: php, laravel, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'a, trying to make a simple login flow with MSGraph and Laravel. I've bin trying to follow working steps from postman API calls. But I simply can't get the flow to make sense.

I found the Postman collection here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman

Here I can login with the delegated login flow. But when I'am trying to convert it to PHP I can't get it to work.

Here is my login flow

```
//protected $token = '';
public function connect()
{
    $clientId = env("MSAP_CLIENT_ID");
    $secretId = env("MSAP_SECRET_ID");
    $tenantId = env("MSAP_TENANT_ID");
    $redirect = env("MSAP_LANDING_URL");
    $guzzle = new Client();


    $authUri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . env('MSAP_TENANT_ID', 'common') . '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
    $url = $authUri . '?' . http_build_query([
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => $clientId,///$clientId,
            'state' => '12345',
            'scope' => 'User.Read',
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect
        ]);
    return redirect($url);

}

public function home()
{
    parse_str(parse_url(URL::full())['query'], $params);
    if (count($params) >= 3) {
        //dd($params);
        //todo get token
        //to do get me
        $this->getMe($this->getToken($params['code']));
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}

private function getToken($code)
{

    $clientId = env("MSAP_CLIENT_ID");
    $secretId = env("MSAP_SECRET_ID");
    $tenantId = env("MSAP_TENANT_ID");
    $redirect = env("MSAP_LANDING_URL");
    $guzzle = new Client();

    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token';

    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $clientId,///$clientId,
            'client_secret' => $secretId, // $clientSecret,
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => 'user.read',
            'Authorization'=> 'Basic'.$code
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());

    $token->access_token;
    //dd($token);
    return $token->access_token;
}

private function getMe($token) {
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
    ];
    $guzzle = new Client([
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
    $user = json_decode($guzzle->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me')->getBody()->getContents());

    dd($user);
}
```

And here is my result
[image]

Comment: Check what the token endpoint actually returned first of all.

Comment: First i Get the code Basic {code} then I use that to recieve a baerer token.

Comment: Yes but what was the actual _result_ of trying to get the token.

Comment: Ohh :) I create a url to login (the connect method). This actually validates and sends med to the redirect link. with some parametes (code, session_state and state) Afterwords I use the code to get a access_token. Then use that token to get "/me" logged in user data?